# Door speakers rain damage

Tags: chevrolet, damage, cobalt, speakers, weather-dependent

I recently installed new front door speakers in my 2009 Cobalt, and they've sounded great until a rainstorm we had yesterday. Now, they are much quieter (when I fade the audio all the way to the rear, it is much louder even though I am sitting in the front). After a little research I found that rain is a common issue with Cobalt door speakers.

The previous front speakers, when I got the car, were not working with no sound at all, probably also due to rain.

I did install the new speakers into the car's stock speaker brackets by breaking out the old speakers.

Does anyone have any experience with this, or ways to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Fit new speakers again but protect them from water damage, did your research explain how the water gets in...

Answer (score 1):

In almost all cars inner part of the door isn't sealed from the outside. When rain falls water gets to the glass, then goes down and enters inner part of the door and then all the way down and through the drain holes it goes out of the door (btw if these drain holes are clogged with some dirt water keeps inside the door for some time and causes corrosion).

Usually car manufacturers use plastic (polyethylene) film to seal the door and protect trims, switches and other electronics from the water.

If I were you I wold either install water resistant marine speakers or create some kinda cover from thick polyethylene film and put it inside the speaker bracket to protect speaker from the back.